# Looking to compress just a PGS stream of a video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, compression, video-conversion, video-encoding

I have a video stored as an mkv with pgs subtitles. I noticed when I burn the subtitles in with this command here`ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -filter_complex [0:v][vid];[0:s:1][sub];[vid][sub]overlay[v] -map [v] -map 0:a:0 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy 'output.mp4'` my file size doubles? Is there any way to compress just the PGS stream and not the original video so that I can still burn in the subtitles but not double the file size of that of the original video? From what I have read you can add x265 params to the PGS overlay but I have been unsuccessful at that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, with ffmpeg there's no way to burn a subtitle track without reencoding the whole video stream.

In your command line you do not specify any target bitrate or a quality factor, so ffmpeg applies some default of his own and you have no control on the output size. You should use one of them:

target video bitrate: `-b:v 2000k` (in kb/s)

or

quality factor: `-crf 20` (the lesser value-->the higher quality-->the bigger file)

(The other question is: do you really need to burn the subtitle?)